# How to get rid of the unwanted control information in Solidity listing displayed as figure

Tags: listings

I am using dissertation template. Following is the link:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/yyjwyqtvzfwt#ef4aff

Can anybody get access to all my documents using the above link?

I am trying to represent the Solidity code listing as figures. I have written the following code listing for representing as a figure as shown below:

```
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Example of Information Flow Rules}
\begin{lstlisting}
[language=Solidity, label={lst:Etahinter1}]
contract IFR{
function initOwner(address _owner) public { owner = _owner;}
function EasyTokill() public {
   if (msg.sender == owner)
   { /* sensitive code like selfdestruct or Ether transfer statement */ ... }}
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{figure}
```

The resultant latex listing shows the following unwanted line at the top sometimes and sometimes not:

[language=Solidity, label={lst:Etahinter1}]

Please guide me how to get rid of the above line.
Zulfi.

Comment: you could more helpfully supply a test document, it does not have to have any words from your real document but should be a complete small document that people can test. It is safest to put the optional argument immediately after `\begin{lstlisting}`

Comment: Please post a minimal example here. Posts should not rely on external links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optional argument needs to be straight after `\begin{listing}` otherwise it is read verbatim as part of the listing.

This is shown in the second block below, but I get

```
! Package Listings Error: Couldn't load requested language.

See the Listings package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.20 ...language=Solidity, label={lst:Etahinter2}]
                                                  
? 

! Package Listings Error: language solidity undefined.

See the Listings package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.20 ...language=Solidity, label={lst:Etahinter2}]
                                                  
?
```

But perhaps you have a local extension that defines this listings configuration.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Example of Information Flow Rules}
\begin{lstlisting}
[language=Solidity, label={lst:Etahinter1}]
contract IFR{
function initOwner(address _owner) public { owner = _owner;}
function EasyTokill() public {
   if (msg.sender == owner)
   { /* sensitive code like selfdestruct or Ether transfer statement */ ... }}
}
\end{lstlisting}

\bigskip \hrule \bigskip

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Solidity, label={lst:Etahinter2}]
contract IFR{
function initOwner(address _owner) public { owner = _owner;}
function EasyTokill() public {
   if (msg.sender == owner)
   { /* sensitive code like selfdestruct or Ether transfer statement */ ... }}
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Based on your comments, I have developed Figure 4.2. It does not have unwanted listing control, but it has a huge horizontal line above the figure, and there is a huge space. Please guide me how to get rid of the huge horizontal line and huge space .  https://www.overleaf.com/project/6531bd5d181592ed690d9384    Zulfi.

Comment: the `\bigskip \hrule \bigskip` is just for this example to separate the two listings, not for you to copy @user2994783

Comment: Actually the problem was in the line: \begin{lstlisting}[language=Solidity, label={lst:Etahinter2}]. Previously I was inserting a carriage return after: \begin{lstlisting}. Actually I was writing: "\begin{lstlisting}" and in the next line I was writing:"[language=Solidity, label={lst:Etahinter2}]". Thanks a lot. God blesses you.

Comment: @user2994783 yes that's what I show here "The optional argument needs to be straight after \begin{listing}"